# STM32CubeIDE / Keil IDE = Is code portable for STM32 Discovery board?

Tags: stm32, keil

Somebody gave me an STM32F429I-DISC1 board to build a simple data logger.  I (blindly) went to the STM website and grabbed the STM32CubeIDE and ran the demo...board works fine.  Now I'm trying to get started on the project itself.

I see many examples of projects with the Keil IDE.  Can I just grab the source code from these examples and import it into STM32CubeIDE?  I assume I'll need to reconfigure (?) the I/O pins and hardware references, but will it generally work?

Comment: I don't understand what, where from and where to you want to port. The title is saying  A, the question is asking about B and C.

Comment: There are multiple IDE's you can use the program the STM32F29I-DISC1 board.  They include the STM32CubeIDE and the Keil IDE.  There are free and for pay versions of each as well.  Here is an example of a project ( https://www.instructables.com/id/STM32F4-Discovery-part2-ADC-Graph/ ) that uses the Keil IDE.  Can this and others be imported into the STM32CubeIDE, compiled and deployed (easily) to the board?

Comment: STM32Cube can be integrated with many mainstream IDEs and toolchains. You can read about the one you are interested in if you google "STM32Cube integration with *<your environment>*"

Comment: I know it can be integrated with multiple IDE's.  Does that mean that the code is completely portable?  Does that mean I can take any code from any IDE and import it into any other IDE, compile, and provision the board?  That's the question I'm asking.

Comment: The code portability is not depending on IDE but on the toolchain used (that is - the compiler). The *de-facto* standard open-source compiler is `gcc`. Some commercial solutions such as Keil might give you an option to use a proprietary `armcc`  toolchain as well.

Comment: Ok... so if the project was made with Keil and used gcc it is portable to STM32CubeIDE with gcc.  If the project was made with Keil armcc, then it may not be portable?

Comment: armcc and gcc are *mostly* compatible, so I would expect even Keil to generate portable code. But can't tell for sure as never worked with it.